# Validating table rows in a LiveCycle form

Tags: livecycle

I am developing a LiveCycle form that has a table on it that can have a variable amount of rows.  I want to only validate it if there is data in one of the columns but not all of them.  So I would skip the validation if the row is blank or all the columns in that row are filled in.

Any ideas how to do this.  How would I loop through the rows of a table.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: I have figured out how to loop thru the table rows.  I just need to know how to manually flag a row as being invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tweat your answer a little bit by replacing *resolveNodes* that is quite slow.

- In order to get row count you can use instanceManager `TrainerForm._TrainerTable.count`
- To get a specific item from row list use `<RowName>.all.item(index)`. Be carefull while using this construct because it requires a least one row. `Row` is a shourtcat for `Row[0]`.

Here is your code with with my upgrades:

```
var rowCount = TrainerForm.TrainerTable._TrainerData.count;
for (var i=0;i<rowCount;i++)
{
    if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerName.rawValue == null && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerPrepHrs.rawValue == null && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerArea.selectedIndex == -1 && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerActivity.rawValue == null ) 
        ;//check the case where all rows are blank which is valid
    else
    {
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerName.rawValue == null)
        {
           TrainerTableValid = false;          
           TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerName.ui.#textEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerPrepHrs.rawValue == null)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerPrepHrs.ui.#numericEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerArea.selectedIndex == -1)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerArea.ui.#choiceList.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerActivity.rawValue == null)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData.all.item(i).TrainerActivity.ui.#textEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good tweak to the code but how would you handle #textEdit.border.fill.color.  I thought you needed to use resloveNode for all characters such as #.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your script in validate event of your cells or whole row. The result of validation script is determined by the last line result (*true* or *false*); To make validations failure visible you can set form level validation (*File->Form Properties->Form Validation->Color Failed Fields*).

Another approach (that I personally prefer) is setting field as required using code `fieldName.manadatory = "error"` when some conditions are met. In order to make field optional just put `fieldName.manadatory = "disabled"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.  First I made all fields optional.  Then I execute this code from a click event of a button.

```
    var fields = xfa.resolveNodes("TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData[*]");
for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
{
    if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerName.rawValue == null && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerPrepHrs.rawValue == null && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerArea.selectedIndex == -1 && 
        TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerActivity.rawValue == null ) 
        ;//check the case where all rows are blank which is valid
    else
    {
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerName.rawValue == null)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            xfa.resolveNode("TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData[" + i + "].TrainerName.ui.#textEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerPrepHrs.rawValue == null)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            xfa.resolveNode("TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData[" + i + "].TrainerPrepHrs.ui.#numericEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerArea.selectedIndex == -1)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            xfa.resolveNode("TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData[" + i + "].TrainerArea.ui.#choiceList.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
        if (TrainerForm.TrainerTable.resolveNode("TrainerData[" + i + "]").TrainerActivity.rawValue == null)
        {
            TrainerTableValid = false;          
            xfa.resolveNode("TrainerForm.TrainerTable.TrainerData[" + i + "].TrainerActivity.ui.#textEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,0,0";
        }
    }
}
```